# Car Hire Double Booking Prevention

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I have been searching the internet and now require some clarification.

I am building a car hire website where customers can book out a luxury car for the weekend or for a week.

The issue I have is to create a way to prevent 2 people booking the same car across the same dates. I have read about TRANSACTION and wanted to confirm how it works. I have read a lot of articles but nothing has confirmed how I think it works.

When a TRANSACTION has been started does it temporarily insert the data into the database which then prevents anyone else inserting the same data? Or does it just store the insert in the users browser and only inserts once committed?

TRANSACTION sounds like what I need but I just need that confirming before I go ahead with it. Otherwise I need another solution.

Thanks in advance and I hope this made sense to whomever has taken the time to read it.

Comment: For reference, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_%28database_systems%29

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways to solve this problem:

A `UNIQUE` index that incorporates car and booking time so that it's impossible to create two records with the same combination:

```
INSERT INTO bookings (car_id, date, customer_id) VALUES (1, '2014-09-29', 1903)
```

Where if there is a pre-existing booking on that date your `INSERT` will fail with an error. The `bookings` table here represents the availability of a particular car on a particular date, and if it's booked, then what customer booked it. You'd probably want to add on another layer to represent multi-day bookings.

Alternatively, a flag on the booking table that is normally `NULL` but can be set when booked, though your update checks that it was successful:

```
UPDATE bookings SET customer_id=1903 WHERE id=4535 AND customer_id IS NULL
```

That way you won't be able to re-book an already booked car.

Comment: Thank @tadman this sounds like the kind of thing I need to do.

SO if I used the same idea you mentioned how would I then manage a booking that is abandoned and not completed after so many minutes allowing the car to be booked by someone else?

Comment: If you want to reserve bookings that might expire if not confirmed, you'll probably want to add a `reserved_at` column of type `DATETIME` so you can periodically release any unconfirmed bookings. You'll need some kind of regular task to trip this, or will need to perform the release before attempting any booking. Either will work.